# How to install BPM on Cloud Process Designer using Installation Manager?

Tags: ibm-bpm

I am using the IBM BPM on Cloud environment to build business processes.  I also have other on premises IBM BPM instances.  This means that I can't simply install the Process Designer that comes with BPM on Cloud because multiple Process Designers can't co-exist through default installation.   What I found is that I can install multiple Process Designer instances using IBM Installation Manager but after installing Process Designer for BPM on Cloud, it "doesn't work".   How can I install Process Designer for BPM on Cloud using IBM Installation Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a recipe/trick that can be used to install Process Designer for BPM on Cloud using IBM Installation Manager that has been found to work.  Here is that recipe.

1. Download Process Designer from the BPM on Cloud web site.  It will arrive as a ZIP.
2. Extract the ZIP content.
3. Use IBM Installation Manager to install the installation repository found at `./IMPD85`
4. Ensure that during installation you select a distinct installation group from any other Process Designer instances you already have.
5. Once installed, find the directory into which the new Process Designer was placed.  This is the directory you named during the Installation Manager steps.  I called mine `C:\IBM\ProcessDesigner\IBMoC`.
6. Copy the `eclipse.ini` file that you will find in the root of the extracted Process Designer that you unzipped.  Copy this and replace the `eclipse.ini` found in the installation location generated by Installation Manager.
7. Copy the `teamworks` folder from the extracted Process Designer directory to the directory in which Installation Manager created the installed version.  This will copy the directory structure `teamworks\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.bpm.saas.auth-xxx.jar`.   This last step was the one I had missed previously.  This is what engages the security authentication with BPM on Cloud.

This recipe has been tested with IBM BPM 8.5.7 CF 2017.06.